# How to get slash command name using python for discord bot

Tags: python-3.x, discord, disnake

Currently I am using on_message() for reading message.

So I would like to get the command name and call specific function based on command name.

Comment: the question needs sufficient code for a minimal reproducible example:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Try to look up for Slash_Commands, even if you include more details in your question it wouldn't be possible to cover everything in one answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone is looking for the same then here is the answer:

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
   cmdName = message.interaction.name
```